# Measure Counts Doubled in SSAS based on where dimension is referenced in MDX statement

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, olap-cube

I updated and reprocessed a cube this weekend. It seemed that everything went fine since everything processesed as expected. However, this morning it seems like the data for one Measure, for one partition (Claim Count year:2023 Quarter:3)the counts are doubled. The data in the Tables and views that the cube ingests is accurate, so I can rule that out. The biggest difference is how the measure is interacting with one of our date dimensions. If I put the date dimension only ON ROWS, the counts are doubled. See MDX below

```
 SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Claim Count] } ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY { ([Date - Batch Submission].[Date].[Date].ALLMEMBERS ) } DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS FROM ( SELECT ( { [Office].[Office ID].&[6ECC4DAB-CA7B-4333-8D10-9869E1AFCF74] } ) ON COLUMNS FROM [Claim]) WHERE ( [Office].[Office ID].&[6ECC4DAB-CA7B-4333-8D10-9869E1AFCF74] ) CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

However, if I filter the query using the same dimension but in the filter statment targeting a particular day that would have been one of many visible dates from the above MDX query, then the figures are correct

```
 SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Claim Count] } ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY { ([Date - Batch Submission].[Date].[Date].ALLMEMBERS ) } DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS FROM ( SELECT ( { [Date - Batch Submission].[Date].&[2023-09-01T00:00:00] } ) ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( { [Office].[Office ID].&[6ECC4DAB-CA7B-4333-8D10-9869E1AFCF74] } ) ON COLUMNS FROM [Claim])) WHERE ( [Office].[Office ID].&[6ECC4DAB-CA7B-4333-8D10-9869E1AFCF74] ) CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

I'm not familiar enough with the inner workings of cube processing to know what might have happened, the only thing I can think of is that I might have Process updated the dimensions twice before doing a data process for the measure partition itself. I'm not sure why that might have caused it, but it might be important. At this point the only fix I can think of is to do a full or default reprocess for this partition later tonight.

PS: the mdx statements where generated by the query designer using the Cube Browse feature.